# Avoid Error When Selecting From a Table Which Does Not Exist

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, if-statement, select

How do I avoid an error (or replace the error with a meaningful comment) when selecting from a table that does not exist?

I have two boxes on a webpage. The user specifies a table-name in the first, I run a query based on that table-name and use the results of that query to populate the second [dropdown] box (using javascript).

All works well until the user specifies a table which does not exist. The query fails and the [dropdown] box is populated with an 'ugly' error. I would prefer it to be populated with 'Table does not exist'.

Because the function [php] code is used for many purposes it cannot be amended and I can only run 'simple' queries in it. I cannot use a stored procedure.

I have tried many ways to create this effect without success. To illustrate, I am looking for something with the following logic:-

```
SELECT IF 

(SELECT COUNT(TABLE_NAME) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_xxxxx') = 0 

THEN 'Table Not Found'

ELSE

(SELECT id, name FROM table_xxxxx WHERE condition blah blah)

END
```

where table_xxxxx is specified by the user and substituted out

Thanks

Comment: Problem with doing it in 1 SQL statement is that when MySQL parses the SQL it will check for tables existing - which is what your trying to get round.  You would be better doing your 'check table exists in information schema' first and then only do the second SQL if it's found.  Easily enough done in PHP.

Comment: @Nigel Ren...Ok... thanks... looks like that's the only option...

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use try ... catch block to eliminate 'ugly' error and show 'good' (or 'bad') error.

Comment: thanks Ivan... as per you and Nigel Ren... looks like handling it in PHP is the only option....